# Qt5 getting access to data in one form from another

Tags: c++, qt, data-transfer

How to get access to data in one form from another?

I have two forms: 
main form:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "manualform.h"
#include "key.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

Key cryptKey;

void MainWindow::on_autoKeyBtn_clicked()
{
    cryptKey.createAuto();
    QString output = cryptKey.toStrg();
    ui->keyField->setText(output);
}

void MainWindow::on_manualKeyBtn_clicked()
{
    ManualForm form;
    form.setModal(true);
    form.exec();
}
```

and the second:

```
#include "manualform.h"
#include "ui_manualform.h"
#include "key.h"

ManualForm::ManualForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ManualForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

ManualForm::~ManualForm()
{
    delete ui;
}

Key key;

void ManualForm::on_confirmBtn_clicked()
{
    this->close();    
}

void ManualForm::on_resetBtn_clicked()
{

}

void ManualForm::on_checkBox00_toggled(bool checked)
{
        Coord coord(0,0);
        ui->checkBox09->setDisabled(checked);
        ui->checkBox99->setDisabled(checked);
        ui->checkBox90->setDisabled(checked);
        key.add(coord);
}
```

It's assuming that Key object will be created in ManualForm and transfered to MainWindow or ManualForm will get access to cryptKey of MainWindow. But it's a promlem, that I can`t solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `cryptKey` on the heap and pass it to your new form with [signals and slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). Additionally, you can use [QPointer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html) for protection in case your other form deletes the object.

You have to define a signal in MainWindow and a slot in ManualForm and cryptKey preferably as a class object in ManualForm. Then you use `emit` to send the object to your ManualForm. You will probably have to use `qRegisterMetaType` as well to register the object.

Comment: May be there any problems about it because Key object is <vector> of myClass objects?

Comment: You shouldn't pass the local objects from MainWindow to ManualForm. The solution is to create a slot in MainWindow if you want to modify Coord and emit it from ManualForm.

Comment: What about deleting Key object from heap? There is "C2059: syntax error: 'delete' " while using "delete cryptKey;"

Comment: `delete cryptKey;`  in destructor should be fine. Or you allocate it as parent (this). Syntax error means you have probably misspelled something,